# How to make curved plane?

Tags: bezier-curves, curve-modifier

Im looking to make something like the below example, e.g. curved / wavy paper

I read that I could add a curve, and then a curve modifier to the plane. I tried that but it doesn't seem to 'bend' the plane, it just turns it into some weird angled shape (see the bottom screenshot).

[image]

[image]

Comment: your paper needs to be subdivided otherwise it can't bend, but please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hello, 303.. I think it is fair to call this a duplicate, as Emir has suggested. If for some reason the linked answers don't work for you, edit to point out why not, and we can re-open for you.